# How to execute SP with arguments 'table of foo'?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, arguments, sqlplus

Using sqlplus how can I execute a stored procedure which has arguments which are 'table of foo' ?

So for instance in the following package how can I execute 'Get_AnnotationsForEmp' ?

```
create or replace PACKAGE "PKG_DROM"   as
    TYPE tblCostCentreIdentifier    IS TABLE OF BLA_COST_CENTRE.CCE_IDENTIFIER%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    TYPE tblCCEAutoID       IS TABLE OF BLA_COST_CENTRE.CCE_AUTOID%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    --++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    --
    --++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    PROCEDURE Get_AnnotationsForEmp(
        EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID_IN      IN BLA_EMPLOYEE.EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
        CCE_IDENTIFIER_OUT  OUT tblCostCentreIdentifier,
        CCE_AUTOID_OUT      OUT tblCCEAutoID);

    PROCEDURE Get_PastAnnotationsForEmp(
        EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID_IN      IN BLA_EMPLOYEE.EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
        CCE_IDENTIFIER_OUT  OUT tblCostCentreIdentifier,
        CCE_AUTOID_OUT      OUT tblCCEAutoID);
END PKG_DROM;
```

If the procedure was in a package 'BAR' and looked like this ...

```
PROCEDURE FOO (ID IN NUMBER);
```

... then I know I could execute it like this :

```
declare
    r number;
begin
    r := BAR.FOO (1);
end;
```

but how can I extend that idea to accomomdate the OUT arguments which are 'table of' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By declaring the variables using the package.type syntax:

```
DECLARE
  outTBL     PKG_DROM.tblCostCenereIdentifier;
  outAutoTBL PKG_DROM.tblCCEAutoID;
BEGIN
  PKG_DROM.GET_AnnotationsForEmp(id, outTBL, outAutoTBLZ);
END;
```